# PEARライブラリを使ってメール送信を行った際の文字化け

Tags: php, postfix

PEARライブラリを使ってマルチパートメールを送信したいと考えております。

参考サイト：http://www.phpbook.jp/pear/pear_mail/index9.html

ところが題名と本文のところで、文字化けが起こってしまいます。

```
<?php

require_once("Mail.php");
require_once("Mail/mime.php");

$params = array(
  "host" => "mailsvr-01.local",
  "port" => 587,
  "auth" => false

);

$mailObject = Mail::factory("smtp", $params);

$recipients = "hoge15@mailsvr-01.local, hoge13@mailsvr-01.local";

$body = "テストです。";
$body = mb_convert_encoding($body, "ISO-2022-JP", "auto");

$mimeObject = new Mail_Mime("\n");
$mimeObject -> setTxtBody($body);

$bodyParam = array(
  "head_charset" => "ISO-2022-JP",
  "text_charset" => "ISO-2022-JP"
);

$body = $mimeObject -> get($bodyParam);

$addHeaders = array(
  "To" => "hoge15@mailsvr-01.local",
  "From" => "hoge13@mailsvr-01.local",
  "Subject" =>mb_encode_mimeheader("テストメール")
);

$headers = $mimeObject -> headers($addHeaders);

$mailObject -> send($recipients, $headers, $body);


?>
```

受け取っメールを表示すると、下記のようになります。

```
[root@mailsvr-01 new]# cat 1452663570.Vfd00Ic3784M864173.mailsvr-01.local
Return-Path: <hoge13@mailsvr-01.local>
X-Original-To: hoge13@mailsvr-01.local
Delivered-To: hoge13@mailsvr-01.local
Received: from localhost (mailcli-01.local [192.168.100.40])
        by mailsvr-01.local (Postfix) with ESMTP id C27E8A388D;
        Wed, 13 Jan 2016 14:39:30 +0900 (JST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-2022-JP
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
To: hoge15@mailsvr-01.local
From: hoge13@mailsvr-01.local
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?w6PCg8KGw6PCgsK5w6PCg8KIw6PCg8Khw6PCg8K8w6PCg8Kr?=

=1B$B%F%9%H$G$9!#=1B(B
[root@mailsvr-01 new]#
```

どこの設定を見直せばよいかご教授いただけますでしょうか。

以上、お手数ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ソースコードとコマンドの実行ログをコードブロックで整形しました。これらをそのまま貼り付けると記号やスペースが正しく表示されないことがあるため、範囲選択してエディタ上部の `{}` を押し、コードブロックを使うようにしてください。 参考： http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/8000

Comment: @unaristさん

ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、本文が一件訳の分からない文字列になっているのは正しい挙動です。元々の電子メールの規格では件名や本文にASCII文字以外を使うことは想定されておらず、その枠組みの中で他の言語を書く際にはASCII文字だけになるよう符号化して送ることとされました。その符号化を行った結果が

```
=1B$B%F%9%H$G$9!#=1B(B
```

なので、これは問題ありません。メールソフトを通せば正しく日本語で表示されます。

一方、件名はその符号化（MIMEエンコード）が正しく行われていません。

[`mb_encode_mimeheader()`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.mb-encode-mimeheader.php) でその処理を行っているのですが、この関数は `mb_internal_encoding()` 等で設定される内部エンコーディングから ISO-2022-JP や UTF-8 への変換を行い、ヘッダ用の符号化を行います。質問に記載された送信結果から推測するに、この `mb_internal_encoding()` が正しく指定されていないため、意図せぬ文字コード変換が行われています。

基本的に [`mb_internal_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) にはソースコードの文字コードを指定します。加えて、日本語圏のメールソフトの慣習に合わせて処理を行うために、 [`mb_language()`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.mb-language.php) も設定しておくとよいでしょう。

まとめると、mb_**系の関数を呼び出す前に以下の二行を実行します。

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); // もし違う文字コードであれば変更してください
mb_language('ja');
```

なお、これらの設定は php.ini でも行うことができます。

参考： [日本語利用の為の設定(mbstring) - php.iniの設定 - PHPインストールと初期設定](http://www.phpbook.jp/install/phpini/index5.html#section2)

Comment: @unaristさん
上記の2行を追加したらメーラーで正しく日本語表示されました。ありがとうございます。